# Needing help in displaying information in php

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a side project and I have made some nice progress over the last few days, but I have run into an issue.  I'm working with php, mysql, and bootstrap.  The side project is dealing with a movie collection.  I got most of the information showing how I want, but the genres.  I can display all the genres with a groupconcat on mysql side, but I would like them to be links so that a user can click on them and bring up a page with all the movies with that genre.  If I don't use the groupconcat I just get one genre showing.

Here is how the tables are setup in the database.

Movies have all the basic info like plot, duration, type, category.  The primary key is a Code column.
Genres is another table holding all the genres information.  It also has a code pk.
Then there is a MovieGenres table that links the both of them.

Movies
|code | PK|

Genre
|Code|PK|
|Genre| |  Full genre name

MovieGenres
|MovieCode|PK|
|GenreCode|PK|

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for the site part

```
<?php 
    require '../database.php';
    $Code = null;
    if ( !empty($_GET['Code'])) {
        $Code = $_REQUEST['Code'];
    }

    if ( null==$Code ) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "
          SELECT 
            Movies.Code, Title, Plot, Movies.Type, 
            Movies.Category, Image, Score, Rated, Alt, Status, 
            YearReleased, Duration, 
            SUBSTRING(Duration, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(Duration) - 3) AS Duration2, 
            TotalEps, Types.code as tcode, Types.Type as ttype,       
            Categories.Code as ccode, Categories.Category as ca, 
            Ratings.Code as rc, Ratings.Rating as rr, Genre 
          FROM Movies, Types, Categories, Ratings, MovieGenres, Genres 
          WHERE Movies.Type=Types.Code 
          AND Movies.Rated=Ratings.Code 
          AND Movies.Category=Categories.Code 
          AND Movies.Code=MovieGenres.MovieCode 
          AND MovieGenres.GenreCode=Genres.Code 
          AND Movies.Code = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($Code));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        Database::disconnect();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>MovieDB - <?php echo $data['Title'];?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php include '../include/nav.php';?>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Heading/Breadcrumbs -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header"><?php echo $data['Title'];?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="../Images/<?php echo $data['Image'];?>" alt="">
            </div>


<div class="col-md-8 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Plot">Plot</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Details">Details</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Plot" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <p><?php echo $data['Plot'];?></p>
        </div>
        <div id="Details" class="tab-pane fade">
            <li>Alternative Title:  <?php echo $data['Alt'];?></li>
            <li>Type:  <a href="../list/type.php?Code=<?php echo $data['tcode'];?>&Type=<?php echo $data['ttype'];?>"><?php echo $data['ttype'];?></a></li>
            <li>Rated:  <a href="../list/rating.php?Code=<?php echo $data['rc'];?>&Rating=<?php echo $data['rr'];?>"><?php echo $data['rr'];?></a></li>
            <li>Episodes:  <?php echo $data['TotalEps'];?></li>
            <li>Duration:  <?php echo $data['Duration2'];?></li>
            <li>Status:  <?php echo $data['Status'];?></li>
            <li>Genre:  <?php echo $data['Genre'];?></li>
            <li>Category:  <a href="../list/categories.php?Code=<?php echo $data['ccode'];?>&Category=<?php echo $data['ca'];?>"><?php echo $data['ca'];?></a></li>
            <li>Year Released:  <a href="../list/year.php?Year=<?php echo $data['YearReleased'];?>"><?php echo $data['YearReleased'];?></a></li>
            <li>Score:  <?php echo $data['Score'];?></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 hidden-md hidden=-lg">
    <h3>Plot</h3>
    <p><?php echo $data['Plot'];?></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-md hidden=-lg ">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <ul>
            <li>Alternative Title:  <?php echo $data['Alt'];?></li>
            <li>Type:  <a href="../list/type.php?Code=<?php echo $data['tcode'];?>&Type=<?php echo $data['ttype'];?>"><?php echo $data['ttype'];?></a></li>
            <li>Rated:  <a href="../list/rating.php?Code=<?php echo $data['rc'];?>&Rating=<?php echo $data['rr'];?>"><?php echo $data['rr'];?></a></li>
            <li>Episodes:  <?php echo $data['TotalEps'];?></li>
            <li>Duration:  <?php echo $data['Duration'];?></li>
            <li>Genre:  <?php echo $data['Genre'];?></li>
            <li>Status:  <?php echo $data['Status'];?></li>
            <li>Category:  <a href="../list/categories.php?Code=<?php echo $data['ccode'];?>&Category=<?php echo $data['ca'];?>"><?php echo $data['ca'];?></a></li>
            <li>Year Released:  <a href="../list/year.php?Year=<?php echo $data['YearReleased'];?>"><?php echo $data['YearReleased'];?></a></li>
            <li>Score:  <?php echo $data['Score'];?></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>

        <!-- /.row -->



        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
    <?php include '../include/footer.php';?>

    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB design looks no problem:

```
Movies { Code(PK), ... }
Genres { Code(PK), Genre, Full_Genre_Name }
MovieGenres { MovieCode, GenreCode }
```

However your SQL select everything, and it contains multiple rows of same movie data. You might need one SQL to select a movie, and another SQL to get all its genres:

```
1) SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Code = ?

2) SELECT g.* 
FROM Geners AS g 
JOIN MovieGenres AS mg ON g.Code = mg.GenreCode
WHERE mg.MovieCode = ?
```

Depends on your actual page situation, if there is a select options for Genres on your page already, you might just re-use it and 2) SQL change to:

```
SELECT GenreCode from MovieGenres WHERE MovieCode = ?

<?php
// change to your db functions
$movieGenres = $db->getAll($sql2); 
// show clickable genres links: eg
echo '<h3>Genres:</h3><p>';
foreach ($movieGenres as $g) {
    echo '<a href="/genre/', $g['Code'] ,'">', $g['Genre_Full_Name'] ,'</a>; ';
}
echo '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I thought about it, but didn't know how to implement it in php

Comment: Right now I have the plot in one tab section and details in another and I would like to put genres in the details section.

Comment: If this answer is correct for the original question you should accept it and post a new question if you have further issues